# Apache output compression working for CSS/JS but not PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, php, gzip, deflate

I have this in my `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|php)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Testing files on my site, it seems that `*.js` and `*.css` files are being compressed fine. However, my PHP files are not. These are all direct PHP files, not rewritten in any way or using query parameters - like `http://example.com/folder/page.php`.

Why would this not be working? I'm on shared hosting so can't change the server myself, but is there something specific I can ask my host to change? (Also, I know about using gzip in PHP, I'd prefer a simpler site-wide solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compression can be enabled php site wide with this entry in "php.ini":

```
zlib.output_compression = On
```

or in .htaccess:

```
php_flag zlib.output_compression on
```

This site has a good writeup:

[http://www.mybelovedphp.com/2006/11/29/how-to-use-gzip-compression-on-your-php-websites/][1]